# Hacer referencias a bibliografía que está en otro archivo tex en Latex

Tags: latex

Tengo un archivo main.tex que utiliza *\input* para agregar las referencias, el problema es que cuando estoy en una sección, no puedo hacer referencia a la bibliografía que quiero. Abajo un ejemplo explicativo de lo que tengo:

```
\begin{document}
\input{secciones/desarrollo.tex}
\input{secciones/bibliografia.tex}
\end{document}
```

el archivo *bibliografia.tex* esta hecho de la forma:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{foo}
info. blah blah foo (2019)
\end{thebibliography}
```

Al momento de estar en *desarrollo.tex* y al hacer

```
Estoy escribiendo y quiero hacer referencia a \ref{foo}.
```

me compila

```
Estoy escribiendo y quiero hacer referencia a ??.
```

¿Qué puedo hacer? Los paquetes que estoy utilizando, entre otros, son:

```
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
```

Comment: ¿Has compilado al menos dos veces? En principio aunque tengas las referencias en otro archivo, al incluirlas con `\input{}` es como si estuvieran en el mismo. Sospecho que tu problema es que te ha faltado una compilación. Si tienes una distribución latex moderna puedes usar `latexmk -pdf` para compilar, pues este comando se ocupa de ejecutar latex (y bibtex u otras herramientas si fueran necesarias) todas las veces necesarias para que se completen las referencias cruzadas.

Comment: Otra sugerencia es que te descargues texworks. y puedes generar el pdf también con la opción pdflatex+bibtext (como sugiere el compañero de arriba debes compilar dos veces el código para que haya efecto), o describe más tu problema (algún error, advertencia que aparezca...).

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, en este caso el comando `\cite` debería reemplazar al comando `\ref`. Entonces, `\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}` no es necesario.

Sean:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref} %% no es necesario!!

\begin{document}
\input{secciones/desarrollo.tex}
\input{secciones/bibliografia.tex}
\end{document}
```

el contenido de **/main.tex**,

```latex
Estoy escribiendo y quiero hacer referencia a \cite{foo}.
```

el contenido de **/secciones/desarrollo.tex**, y

```latex
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{foo}
info. blah blah foo (2019)
\end{thebibliography}
```

el contenido de **/secciones/bibliografia.tex**.

Si ahora compila el archivo main.tex dos veces con pdfLatex, el resultado es el esperado:

[image: screenshot of output]

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)